# PyMongo $addToSet not working

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

So i am using `pymongo==3.2.1` and `Mongo 3.2` but for some reason my `$addToSet` (to avoid duplicates) is not working.

I made sure my `checked_on` timestamp matched like for example `ISODate("2016-04-21T00:00:00.000Z")`

My structure is like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("57062e357e254255a531165e"),
    "availability": [
        {
            "checked_on": ISODate("2016-04-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "days": [
                {
                    "available": false,
                    "day": ISODate("2016-04-29T00:00:00.000Z")
                },
                {
                    "available": false,
                    "day": ISODate("2016-04-30T00:00:00.000Z")
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "is_active": true,
    "updated_on": ISODate("2016-04-21T13:41:12.449Z")
}
```

I have tried both:

```
result = self.db[self.collection_name].update_one(
    {'_id': doc['_id']},
    {
        '$addToSet': {
            'availability': {
                '$each': [
                    {
                        'checked_on': datetime.datetime(
                            date.year, date.month, date.day
                        ),
                        'days': meta['availability']
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        '$set': {
            'is_active': is_active, 'updated_on': date
        }
    }
)
```

and

```
result = self.db[self.collection_name].update_one(
    {'_id': doc['_id']},
    {
        '$addToSet': {
            'availability': {
                'checked_on': datetime.datetime(
                    date.year, date.month, date.day
                ),
                'days': meta['availability']
            }
        },
        '$set': {
            'is_active': is_active, 'updated_on': date
        }
    }
)
```

But duplicates keep appearing, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: So what are you actually expecting to happen? Point is that the with the  combination of `checked_on` and `days` which are both of the properties in the objects in the "set" , if those "differ" in any way from something already in there then it is in fact a "new" item. So either the `checked_on` or `days` and possibly even just the "set" of `day` properties inside that would actually denote the "unique" item. So `$addToSet` cannot handle this, but unless you actually tell us what exactly defines an item as unique, then no-one can help you either.

Comment: @NeilLunn i am not sure i understand what you mean. all these elements inside availability must be unique together

Answer (score 2):

> what am I doing wrong?

You are not doing anything wrong. This is because the value you are trying to add to your array is a document. This is just the expected result as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#behavior).

> If the value is a document, MongoDB determines that the document is a duplicate if an existing document in the array matches the to-be-added document exactly; i.e. the existing document has the exact same fields and values and the fields are in the same order. As such, field order matters and you cannot specify that MongoDB compare only a subset of the fields in the document to determine whether the document is a duplicate of an existing array element.

Comment: i see, so how can i get around that problem and avoid dulplicates with documents?

Comment: i am going to manually check the elements, isn't there a better way to do this?